# No internet connection, DNS error. Have dd-wrt, att DSL, WRT54GS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, dd-wrt

My internet just stopped working a few days ago. The wired connection is fine. When I connect to the router I can no longer connnect wired or wirelessly. I upgraded my router (Linksys WRT54GS) to dd-wrt in case the old firmware was the problem. Still no luck. I have tried using google public DNS and openDNS to the best of my knowledge (I put their DNS addresses into the static DNS field of dd-wrt and changed the DNS addresses in TCP/IP settings) Please any help is appreciate. I really want to be able to fix this.

I am using Windows XP SP3. Here is my current ipconfig/all.

Windows IP Configuration

```
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : omidanaky
    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcast
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : netgear.com
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : NVIDIA nForce Networking Controlle
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1B-24-72-A5-65
```

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : netgear.com
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 4321AG 802.11a/b/g/draft-
```

Wi-Fi Adapter

```
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1A-73-81-8C-0D
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.139
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, June 28, 2013 9:26:19 AM
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, June 29, 2013 9:26:19 AM
```

Comment: It looks like you're getting a good IP from the router, what are your router WAN settings?

Comment: "The wired connection is fine. When I connect to the router I can no longer connnect wired or wirelessly." That doesn't make sense. Also, how did you determine that your issue is a DNS issue? If "your internet stopped working", then using a different DNS provider isn't going to make it work again.

Comment: I notice that your wifi is pulling your routers lan IP as its DNS server address. have you tried alternative servers in the router's DHCP settings? setting the DNS for the wan and setting it for clients is often a different process, done on a different screen.

Comment: Oliver - I determined it is a DNS issue because when trying to load pages I get a DNS error page from Chrome. When using a direct connection to my modem, the internet works. When I try to use my router, wired or wirelessly, I can't connect to the internet. What are the WAN settings I am looking for in the router? I do not know exactly what you mean. I have tried alternate DNS servers. I have set the static DNS in the router settings to both googleDNS and openDNS and changed the DNS setting under the tcp/IP config window to use those addresses.

Comment: I got the wireless to work two nights ago for about 5 minutes by changing the subnet mask in the router settings. Then it stopped working again. I also was able to get it to work for just a second loading google using norton's DNS and then it would not load any other pages. I am so confused.